# Oracle SQL finding matching records on multiple sub queires in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

There are three tables:  CLIENT, MEMBER, and MEMBER_INVOICE.  CLIENT can have many members and member can have many invoices.  I am trying to see how many overall clients overall have the total number of invoices, to where the desired output would be:

```
CLIENT, TOTAL INVOICE
client a, 4
client b, 11
```

The basic table structure is:

CLIENT

```
Name               Null?    Type               
------------------ -------- ------------------ 
ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(38)         
CLIENT_NAME                 VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) 
BILLING_ID                  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

MEMBER

```
Name                        Null?    Type               
--------------------------- -------- ------------------ 
ID                          NOT NULL  NUMBER(38)         
MEMBER_NAME                           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) 
BILLING_ID                            VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENT_ID                             NUMBER(38)
```

NOTE:  CLIENT_ID is tied to the ID of the CLIENT record (I inherited this database and design).

MEMBER_INVOICE

```
--------------- -------- ------------ 
ID              NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
MEMBER_ID                NUMBER(38)   
INVOICE_ID               NUMBER(38)
```

MEMBER_INVOICE is a lookup to the INVOICE and MEMBER table

there is a client_id column on member, and a member_id record on the invoice.  I've tried to break it out into individual queries, but i'm getting very confused.  This is what I've been working on so far

query 1

```
select client_name, billing_id from client WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(billing_id, '^[[:digit:]]+$');   //gives the unique billing id to search the members table
```

query 2

```
select a.member_name,
       count(*)
from member a
  LEFT JOIN member_invoices b ON a.id= b.member_id
group by a.member_name;     // works -- gives me a list of the MEMBER names and the total number of INVOICES for each
```

Since CLIENT can have many MEMBER, I need to plug in query 2 from the above statement, to somehow get a list of the clients name and the total number of invoices under the client's total members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to chain the `join`s:

```
select c.client_name, count(mi.member_id)
from client c left join         
     member m
     on c.id = m.client_id left join
     member_invoices mi
     on a.id = mi.member_id
group by c.client_name;
```

Note that this changed the `count()` so it can return `0` if there are no corresponding invoices.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, it can be

```
select client_name, count(*) 
from CLIENT c, MEMBER m, MEMBER_INVOICE mi
where c.ID = m.CLIENT_ID and m.ID = mi.MEMBER_ID
```

Comment: You may understand the problem.  But do you understand `JOIN`???

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I did with older syntax, right. Or miss of side join is what bothers you?